# how to plot multiple histograms on the same graph from multiple DNA distance files?

Tags: r, histogram, fasta, genetics

I have 100 fasta files and I would like to plot overlapping histograms of genetic distance matrix to see how much overlap there is between bootstrap replicates of DNA data?

I have figured out how to get ape to read each file using:

```
files <- list.files("/Volumes/ALEX_R-HD/", pattern="/Volumes/ALEX_R-HD/xii-27-D")
library("ape")
library("pegas")
library("plyr")
library("dostats")
filenames <- dir(path="/Volumes/ALEX_R-HD/xii-27_D_coccus", full.names="TRUE", pattern="xii-27")
listOfiles <- lapply(filenames, function(x) read.dna(x, format="fasta"))
```

and then generate a genetic distance matrix for each one using:

```
distOfiles <- lapply(listOfiles, function(y) dist.dna(y, model="TN93"))
```

the genetic distance files look like this when I call them from the R console,:

```
[[1]]
               M_51_1_new__ M_51_3_new__ M_51_4_new2__ M_51_5_new2__ M_51_6_new__ M_51_7_new__ M_51_8_new__ madera_1_new__ madera_2_new__  madera_3__ madera_4_new__ madera_5_new__
M_51_3_new__    0.000000000                                                                                                                                                        
M_51_4_new2__   0.000000000  0.000000000                                                                                                                                           
M_51_5_new2__   0.000000000  0.000000000   0.000000000                                                                                                                             
M_51_6_new__    0.000000000  0.000000000   0.000000000   0.000000000                                                                                                               
M_51_7_new__    0.000000000  0.000000000   0.000000000   0.000000000  0.000000000                                                                                                  
M_51_8_new__    0.000000000  0.000000000   0.000000000   0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000                                                                                     
madera_1_new__  0.037124343  0.037124343   0.037124343   0.037124343  0.037124343  0.037124343  0.037124343                                                                        
madera_2_new__  0.037124343  0.037124343   0.037124343   0.037124343  0.037124343  0.037124343  0.037124343    0.000000000                                                         
madera_3__      0.037124343  0.037124343   0.037124343   0.037124343  0.037124343  0.037124343  0.037124343    0.000000000  

and goes on to.... [[100]]
```

where I run into trouble is plotting a histogram of each one, so that each bootstrap will plot on top of the other in the same window, the script below just plots each one in a brand new window and doesn't overlap them:

```
bins=seq(0,0.05,by=0.001)
HistOfiles <- lapply(distOfiles, function(z) hist(z, breaks=bins, main="Histogram of D. coccus   Mexico-types TN93 distances", ylim=c(0,1500), xlab="TN93 distance", ylab="frequency", col=rgb(0,0,0,0.01),  border=rgb(0,0,0,0.01)))
```

I know this can be done the hard way by:

```
bins=seq(0,0.05,by=0.001)
readfile1 <- read.dna("/Volumes/ALEX_R-HD/xii-27_D_coccus/xii-27-D_coccus1", format="fasta")
 distance_TN931 <- dist.dna(readfile1, model="TN93")
 bins=seq(0,0.05,by=0.001)
 hist(distance_TN931, breaks=bins, main="Histogram of D. coccus Mexico-types TN93 distances",   ylim=c(0,1500), xlab="TN93 distance", ylab="frequency", col=rgb(0,0,0,0.01),  border=rgb(0,0,0,0.01))
 lines(density(distance_TN931), col=rgb(1,0,0,0.01))
 par(new=TRUE)
 readfile2 <- read.dna("/Volumes/ALEX_R-HD/xii-27_D_coccus/xii-27-D_coccus2", format="fasta")
 distance_TN932 <- dist.dna(readfile2, model="TN93")
 bins=seq(0,0.05,by=0.001)
 hist(distance_TN932, breaks=bins, ylim="", main="", xlab="", ylab="", col=rgb(0,0,0,0.01),      border=rgb(0,0,0,0.01))
lines(density(distance_TN932), col=rgb(1,0,0,0.01))
par(new=TRUE)
```

.......on to last file

but I think that would be a lot of work, which is fine for 100 files, but if other people who have 1,000's of files (eg. people working from GenBank data etc.) this might be too much.

I also tried going about this another way by using some Unix to paste the different files into a \t separated list of columns by:

```
paste /Volumes/ALEX_R-HD/xii-27_D_coccus/xii-27-D_coccus* /Volumes/ALEX_R-HD/xii-27_D_coccus/blank > /Volumes/ALEX_R-HD/xii-27_D_coccus/blank
```

that files looks like this, and I "" the \t to try and make it clear how they are separated

```
 >name1 "\t" >name1 "\t" >name1 ...... 100 times for each row

 actgactg "\t" actgaca "\t" actgaca

 actgttgc "\t" actgact "\t" actgaca

 >name2 "\t" >name2 "\t" >name2 

 actgactg "\t" actgaca "\t" actgaca

 actgttgc "\t" actgact "\t" actgaca
```

but I can't figure out how to get read.dna to read each column as a separate data matrix, I can get read.table to read the file, but get stuck there,

I am totally stumped at this point as I am a new R user, I have done a lot of looking around on-line for a solution to this and there doesn't seem to be one that I have found that doesn't involve some variant of the hard way to do this as I described above, perhaps lattice can get the job done?

Comment: I'm looking at `?plot.histogram`. How about something like `plot(HistOfiles[[1]])` followed by `lapply(HistOfiles,lines)`?

Comment: I think you could squash all the distances together (tagged by their file) and use `ggplot` to plot them all.  Alternatively you can use `par(new=TRUE)` to get new histograms to overplot.  Can you post a few of the relevant data files somewhere publicly accessible online so someone can write a fully working/testable solution? ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 )

Comment: many thanks to both BlueMagister and Ben Bolker for geting to my question so quickly I will try out both suggestions on my data set and post any solutions, I will also try and post the data set on the tinyurl.com as well,

Comment: I was able to get this to work eventually I found that quartz or x11 can't do semi-transparency and had to copy and past out the command 100 times using par(new=TRUE) and link and open them up as a pdf then it worked great